# ChromeDriver Error: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use selenium with Python to click a button on an HTML web page.Whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

> 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

I'm trying to click the "Play" button on this website: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/python-at-the-us-federal-election-commission/id979020229?i=1000522628049

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/path/to/chromedriver")
time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/python-at-the-us-federal-election-commission/id979020229?i=1000522628049')
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember99"]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/button')
button.click()
```

Comment: Stupid question first: is chromedriver actually located in the path you are specifying?

Comment: `"C:/path/to/chromedriver"` Replace this with the actual path to the chromedriver. Which I assume you have downloaded. Something like `D:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

From the error `'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH` it seems like your chromedriver is not in the `PATH` environment variables. based on your OS check if chromedriver path exists in environment path variable.

Then try with below code: raw string with complete path of .exe of chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver_win64\chromedriver.exe') # complete path with .exe
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using Windows, the path that you've written should look like:

`'C:\\Studies\\PYTHON\\Web Scrapers'`

Windows accepts "\\" when mentioning the path. Attached a screenshot for your reference!

[image: Check this out]

**UPDATE**: This is the code that I had written to scrape a website. You can check it here.

```
for link in links[:5]:
    # Extract the scores
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    path = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options = options)
    driver.get(link)
```

You can check out the entire code **[HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/NeerajKhadagade29/a6de705248aa405a9909ec6446cc790c/web-scraping-javascript-content-full-code.ipynb)**.

Comment: Please post actual code, not a screenshot. Then others can copy the code and tweak it if they need.

Comment: @C.Peck, that's a great suggestion! I've updated my answer. Thanks! :)